# Tomee and Postgres communication with Docker

Tags: database, postgresql, tomcat, docker, apache-tomee

I have 2 Dockerfiles, one for tomee and another one for Postgres:

1. Postgres:

   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-aNPJi4oG7scGZ5cng5SHhzSnM&usp=sharing
2. Tomcat:

   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-aNPJi4oG7sTDZ0cXJoSTVoT3c&usp=sharing

After the creation of the image (postgres-img and tomee-img), I run the containers in this way:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres --name= postgress postgres-image
```

and then tomee

```
docker crete -p 8080:8080 --link postgress:postgress --name=tomcatt tomee-img
```

When I start the containers all work, I can see the web application from browser at 192.168.99.100:8080 and I can see the remote db on PGAdmin by using the ip 192.168.99.100:5432.

As you can see, I link tomee to postgress with --link so in tomee.xml I set `jdbc:postgresql://postgress:5432/postgres`
because I saw that after the linking you can use the alias you choose.
I saw this solution in this thread: [Docker Tomcat container unable to access Postgres container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684210/docker-tomcat-container-unable-to-access-postgres-container)

The problem is that the web application does not communicate with the db that remains always empty. It's like the tomee.xml is useless.

Is there another way to connect the containers?

Comment: what do you mean by `The problem is that the web application does not communicate with the db that remains always empty. It's like the tomee.xml is useless.`? what always remains empty?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the tables in the db don't appear

Comment: Still confused? Why are there no tables in DB? Are you not setting up any tables in the DB?

Comment: The web application have to communicate with the db, for example if I create a model with a form on the web application the correspounding table must be created on the db but this doesn't happen because the web application and the database don't communicate.

Comment: When you create a link between the containers what errors do you get?

Comment: I solved the problem myself, like a stupid I forgot to add the postgres jar in the lib folder of tomee.. it was 2 days that I was searching the problem... sorry and thank you anyway!

Comment: np. Do explore the networking improvements with docker 1.9. You dont need to define links, you can define networks for the containers.

Comment: can you do a tcpdump between them and post the results to cloudshark?